# c++ class is not recognized in the same h file it was defined in

Tags: c++

I have difficulties with a header file:

```
#ifndef NODE_H
#define NODE_H

#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <map>
#include <iterator>

enum TypeSelector{
    //Some values
};

class Node {
public:
    virtual Type getType() {}
    virtual TypeSelector getTypeSelector() {}
    virtual std::string getName() {}
    virtual std::vector<FormalDecl> getDeclaredVector() {}
    virtual void setDeclaredVector(std::vector<FormalDecl> vec) {}
    virtual std::vector<Exp> getExpVector() {}
    virtual void setExpVector(std::vector<Exp> vec) {}
    virtual TypeSelector getTypeSelector() {}
    virtual int getValue() {}
};
 
class FormalDecl : public Node {
public:
    Type t;
    std::string name;
    FormalDecl(Type t, std::string name);
    Type getType() override;
    std::string getName() override;
};

class FormalList : public Node {
public:
    std::vector<FormalDecl> vec;
    FormalList() = default;
    std::vector<FormalDecl> getDeclaredVector() override;
    void setDeclaredVector(std::vector<FormalDecl> vec) override;
};

class Type : public Node {
public:
    TypeSelector t;
    //Used for set, -1 otherwise
    int low;
    int high;
    Type(TypeSelector, int l, int h);
    TypeSelector getTypeSelector() override;
};


class Exp : public Node {
public:
    Type t;
    Exp(Type t);
    Type getType() override;
};

class ExpList : public Node {
public:
    std::vector<Exp> vec;
    ExpList() = default;
    std::vector<Exp> getExpVector() override;
    void setExpVector(std::vector<Exp> vec) override;
};

class Num : public Node {
public:
    int value;
    Num(const char* num);
    int getValue() override;
};

class Id : public Node {
public:
    std::string name;
    Id(const char* name);
    std::string getName() override;

};
 
#endif
```

For some reason I get a huge number of errors, some of which don't even make sense to me, some of them:

```
Node.h:24:34: error:   overriding ‘virtual int Node::getDeclaredVector()’
  virtual std::vector<FormalDecl> getDeclaredVector() {}

Node.h:47:26: error: conflicting return type specified for ‘virtual std::vector<FormalDecl> FormalList::getDeclaredVector()’
  std::vector<FormalDecl> getDeclaredVector() override;

Node.h:66:7: error: ‘Type Exp::getType()’ marked ‘override’, but does not override
  Type getType() override{}

Node.h:39:2: error: ‘Type’ does not name a type
  Type getType() override;
```

I have no idea what causes all those errors, as this is a very simple h file. How can `Type` not be recognized in the same file it was defined? How can I get an `override` error if the signature matches exactly?

Thanks a lot.

The matching .cpp file:

```
#include "Node.h"


FormalDecl::FormalDecl(Type t,std::string name):t(t),name(name){}

Type FormalDecl::getType() {
    return t;
}
std::string FormalDecl::getName() {
    return name;
}

std::vector<FormalDecl> FormalList::getDeclaredVector() {
    return vec;
}

void FormalList::setDeclaredVector(std::vector<FormalDecl> vec) {
    vec = vec;
}

TypeSelector Type::getTypeSelector() {
    return t;
}

Type Exp::getType() {
    return t;
}

std::vector<Exp> ExpList::getExpVector() {
    return vec;
}

void ExpList::setExpVector(std::vector<Exp> vec) {
    vec = vec;
}

std::string Id::getName() {
    return name;
}

std::string Str::getName() {
    return str;
}

int Num::getValue() {
    return value;
}

Type::Type(TypeSelector t, int l, int h): t(t),low(l),high(h){}

Exp::Exp(Type t) : t(t) {}

Num::Num(const char* num) {
    std::string str = num;
    value = std::stoi(str);
}

Id::Id(const char* name): name(name){}

Str::Str(const char* str): str(str){}

SymbolTableEntry::SymbolTableEntry(std::string n, int off, std::vector<Type> t, int scope, bool isFunction) : name(n), offset(off), types(t), scope(scope), isFunction(isFunction) {}
```

Comment: Please give a [mcve]. Your example doesn't compile. We're missing relevant information

Comment: First, `virtual TypeSelector getTypeSelector() {}` is declared twice in Node class. Second, you can't have an incomplete type as a function return type, which you have in `virtual Type getType() {}`. Why does `Type` need to inherit from `Node`?

Comment: @JHBonarius I added the corresponding .cpp file.

Comment: In C++ all types must be declared before they are used.  You use `Type` inside of `Node`, but `Type` doesn't get declared until later in the file.

Comment: @NotAProgrammer Type must inherit from Node because in the software I work with the only type that can be used is Node*.

Comment: `Node.h:39:2: error: ‘Type’ does not name a type` - google the phrase "forwad declaration"

Comment: You must *forward declare* `Type`. Add `class Type;` before `class Node`. There are other changes you need but that is the first.

Comment: @john Thank you, and then getType will have to return Type*?

Comment: This is the reason why we insist on having [mcve] in questions. It helps to focus on the real problem and to reproduce which is often the key before being able to propose a solution. Here there are tons of unnecessary lines, but the declaration of `Type` is missing. So this is far from a [mcve].

Comment: @SergeBallesta I understand, but when I asked the question I didn't know what was the problem.

Comment: @RandomAsker889: We all learn everyday :-). Here you should have learned that you should have tried to reduce your code to a minimal code still exhibiting the problem. Either doing it would have make you find the solution yourself (self learning if very good), or you would have got the solution immediately here.

Comment: @RandomAsker889 No `getType` can still return `Type`, one other change you need to is to move all classes which have a `Type` member (e.g. `FormalDecl`) after the full declaration of `Type`. There maybe other changes, I haven't checked in detail.